# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.util'; 'pandas' is not a package

Tags: python, pandas, pip

i have installed anaconda on a new machine with windows 11. I have installed pandas, but i get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.util'; 'pandas' is not a package

Tried to uninstall the pip and then anaconda and reinstall, still no joy, i get the same message

Comment: I'm guessing you called your script `pandas.py` and so with `import pandas` it tries to import itself.

Comment: No its untitled, trying to call import pandas as pd

Comment: Do you have another file called `pandas.py` in your `PYTHONPATH` so that it shadows the library you want to import?

Comment: Thanks, this was it. Bit of a schoolboy error, much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Try to run `python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall pandas`.

Comment: I now get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Seems its due to this 
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\~umpy.libs\\libopenblas64__v0.3.23-293-gc2f4bdbb-gcc_10_3_0-2bde3a66a51006b2b53eb373ff767a3f.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Does this folder has the access to install packages?

Comment: So not sure what the above issue was, but still getting same error message after  force-reinstall pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.util'; 'pandas' is not a package

Comment: I have even loaded the same versions as i have on my work PC (which works fine) to ensure no conflicts.
pandas 1.5.3
pandas-datareader 0.10.0